# How do I access an object's attribute while iterating through a nested list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have an object defined as follows:

```
class word(object): #object class

    def __init__(self, originalWord=None, azWord=None, wLength=None):
        self.originalWord = originalWord
        self.azWord = azWord
        self.wLength = wLength
```

I have a list called results[], where each index x in the list contains another list of words objects of length x. E.g. in results[3] there is a list of objects of length 3 and one of those objects may be (dog, gdo, 3). I have a value called maxL that represents the length of the list results[]. How do I access (and then print) the attributes I want by iterating through results[] and all of its lists?

This is what I have thus far but I know the syntax is wrong:

```
for x in range(0,maxL):
    for y in results[x]:
        print(results[x][y].azWord)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just iterate the list like so:

```
for row in results:
    for item in row:
        print(item.azWord)
```

Because in your example `results[x][y]` would be incorrect. `y` is an object, not an `int` so you cannot use it to index from `results`. I would just use the above code to pull the objects themselves.

Or to use something closer to your original code

```
for x in range(0,maxL):
    for y in results[x]:
        print(y.azWord) # note y is the object itself, not an index
```

Comment: That seems to work. And as a result I now know my algorithm is doing something funny... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the first loop:

```
for x in range(0,maxL):
```

you are looping through indices. In the second:

```
for y in results[x]:
```

you are looping through *elements*. In this case, through elements of a list. So you can access the attribute like:

```
print(y.azWord)
# ...
```

**Note:**

- I would recommend you to follow [Python naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions). Name your class as `Word`.
- I would also recommend you to use more representative names, like:

  ```
  for i in range(0, maxL):
      for element in results[i]:
          print(element.azWord)
  ```
- You can also loop through elements in the first loop. You should do this unless you want to modify the elements or you need to use indices:

  ```
  for words_list in results:
      for word in words_list:
          print(word.azWord)
  ```